# Appending the data into the access table based on number of record in the table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am new Access VBA, 
My scenario is I want to pick the table name from another table

```
(In same access db (table name as parameter)).
```

Based on the Table name picked from parameter I need to pick le column from the same table(Parmater).Then i want to check distinct le from Parameter. 
Based on distinct le `(4 in my case)` from parameter table i want to append the record to another table `(ULAE).`
The append statement would be as `insert into` with where condition `as LE from parameter table`.

```
Public Sub LinkTables()

Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim stringsql As String
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table Valued Parameter")


While Not rs1.EOF = True

MsgBox rs1![Table_name]
tblname = rs1!Table_name
stringsql = ("SELECT COUNT(LE) from [Table Valued Parameter]")

MsgBox tblname
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL ("SELECT COUNT(LE) FROM [Table Valued Parameter]")
'Next i
DoCmd.SetWarnings True


NEW_TBLNAME = "t_00_unearned_unincepted_alloc_basis_table"
'MsgBox NEW_TBLNAME
'CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append New_tblname

'MsgBox rs1![le]
'Set TD = Nothing

'Dim stringsql As String
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

'stringsql = ("SELECT COUNT(LE) from " & tblname)
'DoCmd.RunSQL (stringsql,False)lename&

cnt = CurrentDb.TableDefs.Count - 1
MsgBox cnt
        For i = 0 To cnt
        lename = rs1![le]
MsgBox lename
DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO " & NEW_TBLNAME & " SELECT * FROM " & tblname & " where le = '" & lename& "')
Next i
DoCmd.SetWarnings True


rs1.MoveNext

Wend
```

The code is giving error 2342 . CMDSQL requires sql statement.

Can someone suggest how can implement it

Thanks for the help

Comment: Your question is unclear. can you please improve your question? Are you trying to export records to a new table based on a parameter in another table?

Answer (score 0):

This was accomplished creating a Function.

```
Function LinkTables()

Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim stringsql As String
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table Valued Parameter")

While Not rs1.EOF = True

'MsgBox rs1![Table_name]
'MsgBox rs1![le]

tblname = rs1!Table_name

legal_entity = rs1.Fields(1)

NEW_TBLNAME = rs1![destination_table]

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO " & NEW_TBLNAME & " SELECT * FROM " & tblname & " where le = '" & legal_entity & "'")

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

rs1.MoveNext

Wend

MsgBox "Tables Refreshed"


End Function
```